# Is the following transformation linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

We've got $f\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x+ 1 \\ y \\x+ y\end{pmatrix}$.

Is this linear or not? Can one determine this by just looking at it, if not, then what is the method?

Comment: What's $f\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: The right hand side must be a linear combination of x and y, which it is not. Just to annoy you, if you embed 2D space in 3D space with the map $\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\to \left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$
then $F\left( \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
   1  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   x+1  \\
   y  \\
   x+y  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$
is linear.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be interesting, and even important, if you could prove the following

**Lemma:** let $\;\Bbb F\;$ be a field, and $\;f:\Bbb F^n\to \Bbb F^m\;$ a function given by

$$f\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\\ldots\\x_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_1,...,x_n)\\\ldots\\f_m(x_1,...,x_n)\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;f_i:\Bbb F^n\to \Bbb F\;\;\text{(scalar functions)}$$

Then, $\;f\;$ is a linear map iff each $\;f_i\;$ is a linear functional iff each $\;f_i\;$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $\;1\;$ in $\;x_1,...,x_n\;$

This means that each $\;f_i\;$ is of the form

$$f_i(x_1,...,x_n)=a_{i1}x_1+a_{i2}x_2+\ldots+a_{in}x_n\;,\;\;a_{ik}\in\Bbb F$$

Thus, your example is **not** a linear map as $\;f_1(x,y)=x+y+1\;$ is *not* a linear functional (or if you prefer the other name, it's not a homogeneous polynomial of degree $\;1\;$ in $\;x\,,\,\,y\;$)

Answer (score 1):

For a linear transformation f(0)=0.But in your example f(0) is not equal to 0.Hence f is not a linear transformation.